# Angular 4.0.1 Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, webpack

Trying to update Angular from 4.0.0 to 4.0.1.

Everything compiles fine, but when opening a site it crashes with

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SomeData: (?, ?, ?).
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:67009:34) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79857:35) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79725:26) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79711:21) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:80000:40) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79928:49 [<root>]
    at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79891:19) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79304:38) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79976:45) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79962:48 [<root>]
    at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79961:30) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:8084/vendor.bundle.js:79925:83 [<root>]
ZoneAwareError @ polyfills.bundle.js:5215
syntaxError @ vendor.bundle.js:67009
CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79857
CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79725
CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79711
CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:80000
(anonymous) @ vendor.bundle.js:79928
CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79891
CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79304
CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79976
(anonymous) @ vendor.bundle.js:79962
CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider @ vendor.bundle.js:79961
(anonymous) @ vendor.bundle.js:79925
CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79891
(anonymous) @ vendor.bundle.js:79893
CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79891
(anonymous) @ vendor.bundle.js:79468
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ vendor.bundle.js:79459
JitCompiler._loadModules @ vendor.bundle.js:90584
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ vendor.bundle.js:90543
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ vendor.bundle.js:90505
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ vendor.bundle.js:9791
PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ vendor.bundle.js:9777
main @ main.bundle.js:3728
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ polyfills.bundle.js:4696
Zone.runTask @ polyfills.bundle.js:4463
ZoneTask.invoke @ polyfills.bundle.js:4758
```

Class `SomeData`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { SomeModel } from './some.model';

@Injectable()
export class SomeData extends ReplaySubject<SomeModel> {
    public name: string = '';
}
```

Class `SomeModel` is a usual class even without any decorators.

How can I fix that?
Seems like Angular team [doesn't write about any breaking changes between 4.0.0 and 4.0.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#401-2017-03-29).

That's what am i using (not all, of course):

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/common": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/core": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/forms": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/http": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/router": "4.0.1",
  "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.13",
  "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
  "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
  "ngc-webpack": "^1.2.0",
  "rxjs": "~5.2.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.8.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.1",
  "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
}
```

I think the problem can be realted to `ngc-webpack` as it asks for `@angular/compiler-cli@^2.4.1`, but it works fine with `4.0.0`. Anyway, I have no ideas how to replace this module.

Comment: I have the same issue and I couldn't find any way to fix it.